# User is Active in other tab even after logout Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am devoloping Asp.net mvc appplication using Asp.net identity framework.User is shown active  and able to access the application in another tab even we logout him in the main tab.I have decorated all my controllers with [Authorize] attribute.And in the Logout method I am clearing the session as well.The same code works fine with my friend .Can u help me where I am going wrong with a solution ASAP.Response would be highly appreciated..

My Logoff method in Account controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

            Session.Abandon();
            Session.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Signout", "Home");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the overloaded method for the SignOut as

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
 DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie,
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    return RedirectToAction("Signout", "Home");
}
```

this helps remove any applications cookies, externalcookie, two factor cookie and remember browser cookie